# Microsoft Graph API - $top parameter not returning correct "@odata.count" for Assignment API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am currently working on fetching [assignments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/educationuser-list-assignments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) from Microsoft Teams using the Graph API. I have two different views: one to display the top 3 assignments along with the total count of all assignments, and another to show all assignments.

To get the top 3 assignments along with the count, I am using the following API call with the "$top=3" parameter:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/education/me/assignments?$expand=submissions&$count=true&$top=3&$orderby=dueDateTime%20asc
```

The response I receive is as follows:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "...",
    "@odata.count": 3,
    "@odata.nextLink": "...",
    "value": [...]
}
```

However, the value of "@odata.count" is always the value of $top param I am passing, regardless of the actual total count of assignments. This is incorrect, as I expect it to display the total number of assignments (in this case, it should show the correct count as 7).

On the other hand, if I fetch all assignments without the "$top" parameter, as shown below:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/education/me/assignments?$expand=submissions&$count=true&$orderby=dueDateTime%20asc
```

The response provides the correct "@odata.count" value along with the complete list of assignments:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "...",
    "@odata.count": 7,
    "@odata.nextLink": "...",
    "value": [...]
}
```

It seems that the "$top" parameter is affecting the "@odata.count" only in the case when I request a limited number of records.

Can anyone suggest a solution to get the correct total count of assignments (7) while fetching only the top 3 records using the Graph API?

*

> Previously, I have successfully used the API to get users, and the
> "@odata.count" was functioning correctly, returning the expected total
> count of users.

- 

Comment: As mentioned in this [query parameter limitation doc](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues/?search=), When using the $count=true query string when querying against directory resources, the @odata.count property will be present only in the first page of the paged data. That might be the reason of getting the value of "@odata.count" same as $top param

Comment: Is there no way to obtain just the count of all assignments without retrieving the entire list?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any other way.